# Merge two lists based on condition

Tags: python, list

I am trying to merge two lists based on position of index, so sort of a proximity intersection.

A set doesn't work in this case. What i am trying to do is match index in each list then if the element is one less than that  of the element in other list, only then i collect it.

An example will explain my scenario better.

**Sample Input:**

```
print merge_list([[0, 1, 3], [1, 2], [4, 1, 3, 5]], 
                 [[0, 2, 6], [1, 4], [2, 2], [4, 1, 6]])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[[0,2],[4,6]]
```

so on position 0 in list1 we have 1, 3 and in list2 we have 2, 6. Since 1 is one less than 2, so we collect that and move on, now 3 is less than 6 but it's not one less than i.e. not 5 so we ignore that. Next we have [1, 2][1, 4], so both index/position 1, but 2 is not one less than 4 so we ignore that. Next we have [2, 2] in list2 both index 2 doesn't match any index in first list so no comparison. Finally we have [4, 1, 3, 5] [4, 1, 6] comparison. Both index match and only 5 in list one is one less than list two so we collect six hence we collect [4,6] meaning index 4 and match etc.

I have tried to make it work, but i don't seem to make it work.

This is my code so far.

```
def merge_list(my_list1, my_list2):
merged_list = []
bigger_list = []
smaller_list = []

temp_outer_index = 0
temp_inner_index = 0  

if(len(my_list1) > len(my_list2)):
    bigger_list = my_list1
    smaller_list = my_list2
elif(len(my_list2) > len(my_list1)):
    bigger_list = my_list2
    smaller_list = my_list1
else:
    bigger_list = my_list1
    smaller_list = my_list2

for i, sublist in enumerate(bigger_list):             
    for index1 , val in enumerate(sublist):           
            for k, sublist2 in enumerate(smaller_list):
                for index2, val2 in enumerate(sublist2):                       
                    temp_outer_index = index1 + 1          
                    temp_inner_index = index2 + 1
                    if(temp_inner_index < len(sublist2) and temp_outer_index < len(sublist)):
                        # print "temp_outer:%s , temp_inner:%s, sublist[temp_outer]:%s, sublist2[temp_inner_index]:%s" % (temp_outer_index, temp_inner_index, sublist[temp_outer_index], sublist2[temp_inner_index]) 
                        if(sublist2[temp_inner_index] < sublist[temp_outer_index]):
                            merged_list.append(sublist[temp_outer_index])
                            break


return  merged_list
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `[[1, 3], [2], [], [], [1, 3, 5]]` and `[[2, 6], [4], [2], [], [1, 6]]` make a lot more sense as input, so the *index* is an actual index?

Comment: @poke, thanks for your comment. In my other code we i build these, i only build the ones with data i.e. no [] lists. I know it makes more readily but is not required and I think somewhat no efficient etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clue what you are doing, but this should work.

First, convert the list of lists to a mapping of indices to set of digits contained in that list:

```
def convert_list(l):
    return dict((sublist[0], set(sublist[1:])) for sublist in l)
```

This will make the lists a lot easier to work with:

```
>>> convert_list([[0, 1, 3], [1, 2], [4, 1, 3, 5]])
{0: set([1, 3]), 1: set([2]), 4: set([1, 3, 5])}
>>> convert_list([[0, 2, 6], [1, 4], [2, 2], [4, 1, 6]])
{0: set([2, 6]), 1: set([4]), 2: set([2]), 4: set([1, 6])}
```

Now the merge_lists function can be written as such:

```
def merge_lists(l1, l2):
    result = []
    d1 = convert_list(l1)
    d2 = convert_list(l2)
    for index, l2_nums in d2.items():
        if index not in d1:
            #no matching index
            continue
        l1_nums = d1[index]
        sub_nums = [l2_num for l2_num in l2_nums if l2_num - 1 in l1_nums]
        if sub_nums:
            result.append([index] + sorted(list(sub_nums)))
    return result
```

Works for your test case:

```
>>> print merge_lists([[0, 1, 3], [1, 2], [4, 1, 3, 5]], 
                      [[0, 2, 6], [1, 4], [2, 2], [4, 1, 6]]) 
[[0, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and answer. Checking it now.

Comment: is the performance for larger lists quadratic or linear for large lists using this solution?

Comment: It is linear. You basically touch everything a constant number of times.

Comment: @user3247054: Sure thing. can i ask what this is for? seems very strange request

Comment: it's related to natural language and query processing etc.

Comment: i am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for function convert_list for input like this [[[14, 2]], [[14, 3]], [[14, 1], [16, 1], [51, 1]]] ( i guess they are nested lists etc) and setting them as key might be causing problem, any suggestion?

Comment: @user3247054: What's your key and what are your values?

Comment: my lists are deeper it seems here's the pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/9kRzfksK
What should i change dictionary creation function to make it work?

Comment: @user3247054: I don't know. that's in a different format than you asked. I don't know what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want it to do:

```
import itertools

def to_dict(lst):
    dct = {sub[0]: sub[1:] for sub in lst}
    return dct

def merge_dicts(a, b):
    result = []
    overlapping_keys = set.intersection(set(a.keys()), set(b.keys()))
    for key in overlapping_keys:
        temp = [key] # initialize sublist with index
        for i, j in itertools.product(a[key], b[key]):
            if i == j - 1:
                temp.append(j)
        if len(temp) > 1: # if the sublist has anything besides the index
            result.append(temp)
    return result

dict1 = to_dict([[0, 1, 3], [1, 2], [4, 1, 3, 5]])
dict2 = to_dict([[0, 2, 6], [1, 4], [2, 2], [4, 1, 6]])

result = merge_dicts(dict1, dict2)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[0, 2], [4, 6]]
```

First, we convert your lists to dicts because they're easier to work with (this separates the key out from the other values). Then, we look for the keys that exist in both dicts (in the example, this is 0, 1, 4) and look at all pairs of values between the two dicts for each key (in the example, 1,2; 1,6; 3,2; 3,6; 2,4; 1,1; 1,6; 3,1; 3,6; 5,1; 5,6). Whenever the first element of a pair is one less than the second element, we add the second element to our `temp` list. If the `temp` list ends up containing anything besides the key (i.e. is longer than 1), we add it to the `result` list, which we eventually return.

(It just occurred to me that this has pretty bad performance characteristics - quadratic in the length of the sublists - so you might want to use Claudiu's answer instead if your sublists are going to be long. If they're going to be short, though, I think the cost of initializing a set is large enough that my solution might be faster.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Checking it now.

Comment: I wish i could just accept your answer based on great explanation and the last part of performance. The lists will be large so performance is indeed a concern. How is claudiu better in terms of performance as compared to your solution?

Comment: @user3247054 Suppose that you have a 1000-element sublist with the same index in `list1` and `list2`. The `itertools.product` loop here will need 1000^2 = one million loops. Claudiu's solution will only require 1000 loops (in the list comprehension), but also a number of set membership tests (still only a linear number of them, though). You know what your data looks like better than we do, so you may as well test both of our solutions and see which one comes out faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge_list(a, b):
    d = dict((val[0], set(val[1:])) for val in a)
    result = []
    for val in b:
        k = val[0]
        if k in d:
            match = [x for x in val[1:] if x - 1 in d[k]]
            if match:
                result.append([k] + match)
    return result
```

Similar to the other answers, this will first convert one of the lists to a dictionary with the first element of each inner list as the key and the remainder of the list as the value.  Then we walk through the other list and if the first element exists as a key in the dictionary, we find all values that meet your criteria using the list comprehension and if there were any, add an entry to the `result` list which is returned at the end.